# Ubuntu Software keeps showing Device Firmware update, even after completing the installation

Tags: updates, software-center, firmware

Hello AskUbuntu community,

I have got a Lenovo T15 Gen 2 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside Windows 10.

I am having troubles with the Device Firmware update. If I click on Install in the Ubuntu Software panel, then it starts downloading but after finishing it gives the same update as before.

This is a pic of the update being installed

[image]

and this is what I see after the installation has been completed, basically the same as before the update

[image]

What should I do?

*Update*

As suggested, I ran `sudo apt update` getting

[image]

and then `sudo apt upgrade` and I got this

[image]

Does that mean that the Device Firmware was updated anyway?

*Update 2*

After running the above-mentioned commands I tried again and this time the update was completed successfully.

Comment: Did running updates in `apt` solve the problem?  FYI: pictures of text are strongly discouraged (especially your terminal). Instead copy-paste and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @Nmath Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Software app sometimes gets false positives in the Updates tab for packages that have already been updated automatically, but the Software app hasn't been refreshed to know about it yet. If you clicked the green *Restart & Update* button and nothing happened, then ignore the update button and the update notification will go away by itself. This unexpected behavior in the Software app does not have any effect on updating software from the terminal which still functions properly in the usual way.